# Question on differential coefficient as a rate measurer

Tags: calculus, derivatives

The question is as follows:
O is a given point and NP a given straight line upon which ON is the perpendicular. The radius OP rotates about O with constant angular velocity ω. Show that NP increases at the rate ω•ON•(sec NOP)^2

I do not know how to approach this question. Could somebody provide me hints as to where do i begin?

Comment: Draw a diagram and using that, find a formula for the distance NP in terms of the angle NOP.

Comment: I'm having trouble with how to find the rate of change of NP. I have to find it's change with respect to time right? Even so how do i inculde the ω within the equations

Comment: The velocity of N is radius × angular velocity measured in radians/sec.